# analysis of complex vector space

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces, complex-numbers

null vector in complex space let is vector scalar product of which to itself is zero, for example let us take  vector  scalar product to itself

$(1,i)*(1,i)=1-1=0$

let us consider all null vector  and show that they represent subspace,  vector space is called subspace if it is belong to main space and two operation : inner operation called as sum (+)  and outer operation (*) is satisfied, for instance

$(1,i)+(1+i)=(2,2i)$

its  scalar product to itself  will be

$(2,2i)*(2,2i)=4+4*(-1)=0$

$\alpha(1,i)=(\alpha,\alpha*i)$

and scalar product is $(\alpha,\alpha*i)*(\alpha,\alpha*i)=\alpha^2-\alpha^2=0$

short question will be: we can easily generate this statements for all type of null vector right?because for more complex vectors, writing is difficult and therefore i decided to show by simple example

EDITED :
also if given vector is  null vector, then its corresponding conjugate is also null vector

for instance $(1,i)$ its conjugate is $(1,-i)$ , scalar product will be

$(1,-i)*(1,-i)=1+(-i*-i)=1+(-1)=0$

Comment: Careful: $\;(1,i)\cdot (1,i)=1^2+i\overline i=1+1=2\neq 0\;$ . Likewise, $\;(2,2i)\cdot(2,2i)=4+4=8$

Comment: wait i*i=1 ? i did not  understand

Comment: Nop: in complex inner product it is defined that the sum of the second components' product is by the second variable's **conjugate**. Thus, in $\;\Bbb C_{\Bbb C}\;$  the usual (euclidean) complex inner product is, with $\;x+iy\rightarrow (x,y)\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ and etc.: $$(x,y)\cdot (a,b):=xa+y(-b)$$

Comment: what i am doing is  coordinate product and sum

Comment: Then you don't get an inner product...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a subspace. Here's a counterexample to the sum operation: take $v = (a, ia)$ and $u = (x, -ix)$, where $a, x\neq0$.
$$\begin{align}
v*v &= a^2-a^2 = 0\\
u*u &= x^2-x^2 = 0\\
u+v &= (a+x, i(a-x))\\
(u+v)*(u+v) &= (a+x)^2 - (a-x)^2\\
 &= a^2+2ax+x^2-a^2+2ax-x^2\\
 &= 4ax \neq 0
\end{align}$$

Comment: i mixed product feature of  complex numbers,ok